# PhotoCaptureDevice's EncodeWithOrientation not setting when screen rotation lock (Portrait) is on in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using PhotoCaptureDevice to capture the photo for my app which is in Portrait Orientation.

but I am facing strange issue as when my device's screen rotation lock is on to portrait, I can not set EncodeWithOrientation Property

```
this.captureDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.EncodeWithOrientation, encodedOrientation);
```

I tried like above but it is not working it always stays 0.

Please help me for way out

thanks in advance